# z-index issue in IE with drop down

Tags: z-index

i know this should be an easy fix, just giving the drop down menu a high z-index. i have given it an index of 300 and it still appears below a nivo slider. i have given the nivo container an index of 1.
i see it appearing this way in IE7, though my client swears he see it in IE8 too and also IE9.

i tried adding "position:relative" but that didnt seem to help much.

my url: http://bit.ly/LF02cf  (to editors: pls leave as a bit.ly link, i dont want the destination link indexed, thanks)

any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: The reason that your client claims it to be that that way in IE9 is because he probably has the compatibility button toggled ON by accident.

Comment: i hear what you say...
i still need to solve the issue for IE7 though... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have really tried to find the problem, but no luck.
What I will recommend you to do is to add this meta to your site:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

It is important that this meta comes after the head tag. This will prevent IE8 and IE9 going into IE7 compatibility mode even if using debugging tools mode.

Comment: Did you try setting it to something big like this.style.zIndex= 1000000000; Can you post a link to a zip archive with the files?

Comment: i am using IE tester, and on IE7 i still dont see a change. i asked the client if they see a change for IE9 and 9, and hopefully they do...  thanks again, i'll report back